# Convex hull for selected features - PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I changed the code to create a convexhull for selected features from this question ([Convexhull for selected features and performing buffer for the resultant convexhull using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137793/convexhull-for-selected-features-and-performing-buffer-for-the-resultant-convexh)) to adapt it to QGIS3, but something does not work. Where is the problem?

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feat = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
geom = feat.geometry()
convexhull = geom.convexHull()
CRS = layer.crs().postgisSrid()
URI = "Polygon?crs=epsg:"+str(CRS)+"&field=id:integer""&index=yes"
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(URI,"convexhull","memory")
mem_layer.startEditing()
feat2 = QgsFeature()
feat2.setGeometry(convexhull)
feat2.setAttributes([1])
mem_layer.addFeature(feat2, True)
mem_layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([mem_layer])
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

EDIT: To be more clear, using this code this is what I get. It's a convexhull for just one feature.

[image]

And this is what I want. It's for all selected features. I reached this using Minimum bounding geometry from processing toolbox.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested your code and made modifications to merge geometry of selected features using [Merge selected feature pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243623/merge-selected-feature-pyqgis) post. You will find below a working correction. After this first solution, you will find an alternate solution using processing from pyqgis

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

selectFeatures = layer.selectedFeatures()

geom = None
for feat in selectFeatures:
    if geom == None:
       geom = feat.geometry()
    else:
       geom = geom.combine(feat.geometry())

convexhull = geom.convexHull()
CRS = layer.crs().postgisSrid()
URI = "Polygon?crs=epsg:"+str(CRS)+"&field=id:integer""&index=yes"
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(URI,"convexhull","memory")

mem_layer.startEditing()
feat2 = QgsFeature()
feat2.setGeometry(convexhull)
feat2.setAttributes([1])
mem_layer.addFeature(feat2)
mem_layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

**Processing alternative from PyQGIS**

```py
from qgis import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()
newconvexhulllayer = processing.run("qgis:minimumboundinggeometry", {
              'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), True),
              'TYPE': 3,
              'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newconvexhulllayer['OUTPUT'])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But also this solution does not work. Maybe the reason is that I'm using a polygon layer?

Comment: I also use a polygon layer... Did you really select a feature in the original layer?

Comment: I've added a GIF to explain my exact process to run the code

Comment: What happens if you select multiple polygons?

Comment: It works and only produce one convex hull polygon (normal with `feat = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]` part)

Comment: I edited my question, probably I was not clear enough.

Comment: Made change to merge all selected geometries. Should do what you expect due to your changes in edited answer

Comment: Sorry, in my case this code produces nothing. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Done an alternative calling script from processing toolbox to do the job. Hope this one works for you

Comment: It says `_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.` Probably there's some error in the layer. Thanks anyway for helping me!

Comment: Did you change the path `'/data/convexhull.shp'` to adapt to your own system? I've made some changes to use "in memory" layer to avoid the issue and another last line to add layer to the current QGIS project

Comment: Now it really works! Sorry about my being noob and thanks

Comment: @ThomasG77 thanks!! I used your code to write a version for a buffer
```result = processing.run("native:buffer",
{'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), True),
 'DISTANCE':2.5,
 'SEGMENTS':5,
 'END_CAP_STYLE':1,
 'JOIN_STYLE':1,
 'MITER_LIMIT':2,
 'DISSOLVE':True,
 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])```